# Find number of arrays with XOR sum as 0

Tags: algorithms, combinations

How to determine number of arrays of length N such that it satisfies below two conditions:

1. Each Value of array is between 0-5 inclusively.
2. XOR sum of all value of the array is 0.

**Example**: Let *N* = 2

*then total arrays with XOR sum zero = 6*

*which are-
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(5, 5)*

So how to find out this in a efficient way?

Comment: How is XOR defined on the digits 2-5?

Comment: @Exodd I assume we write the arguments in binary, with trailing $0$s on one if necessary to make them the same length, then go bitwise.

Comment: Could you solve it with digits $0..7$ instead?

Comment: @Exodd didn't get you. 2^4 = 6, 2^5 = 7. What are you asking?

Comment: @Berci Isn't 0...7 equivalently similar in logic(`combinatorial`, i mean)?